# Rotate a triangle specified by vectors around its center

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, vectors

Well, I know that, in order to rotate a triangle specified by three vectors in $R^2$ we just rotate each vector in the same angle, and to do this we apply the rotation matrix in `2 dimensions`, but it will not exactly rotate the triangle itself, but it's position relative to the origin.

Of course, if we specify the triangle in a way that it will have its center in the origin, then it's gonna rotate around its own center. But can this be done in other way? Can we `rotate a triangle in its own center`, while the center itself `isn't located` at the origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever your definition of "center" is, (call it $c$) subtract it from all the vertices, rotate the resulting triangle around the origin, then add $c$ back to the vertices of the resulting triangle.

Comment: So it can't be represented directly as a matrix vector product?